# Are return values shallow copies in Rust?

Tags: rust

When returning a value from a function as such

```
let x = String::from("Hello");
let y = do_something(x);
```

with

```
fn do_something(s: String) -> String { s }
```

Does Rust do a shallow copy (ie copying the stack value of s into y), or does it do something else ? A shallow copy is made when *passing*, but is it the same behavior when *returning* it ?

Comment: `A shallow copy is made when passing` - this is not true (when the argument type doesn't implement `Copy`, anyway). See [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)

Comment: It's a *move*, thanks to Rust's ownership and lifetime system. No copies, neither shallow nor deep, are made.

Comment: A move is a copy. It doesn't have to exist, but semantically it is there. And yes, the return value is also moved.

Comment: Yes, it's a shallow copy. (It's also known as "move" simply because the original value is no longer accessible and is not destructed.) If you want a deep(er) copy, you have to request it explicitly using `.clone()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A shallow copy is made when passing, but is it the same behavior when returning it?

Ignoring the first part (which is more complicated) and answering just what you want to know: yes, both parameter passing and returning have the same mechanism.

Now to the first part: that mechanism is called "moving", but it also matters whether we're talking about the language semantics (i.e. what the language spec describes as happening according to its abstract execution model) or what actually happens at runtime on a physical computer (which is allowed to be different, so long as the program still does the right thing according to the language spec).

In the language semantics, most types (i.e. those which do not implement `Copy`) are passed as parameters or returned by "moving", not "copying". The difference is that moving implies a change of ownership, whereas copying implies that the original owner retains ownership but the recipient receives ownership of a copy.

In actual reality, a "move" is likely to be implemented as a copy of the stack value (what you call a shallow copy). However, that is not always the case, as the compiler may optimise how it pleases. Particularly if a function is inlined, then there is no need to make any copies of parameters or a return value; the inlined function will be executed in the same stack frame, so the stack value need not be copied to a different frame. Note that Rust's ownership semantics are *required* for this optimisation to work: the inlined function might change the value it takes ownership of (if the parameter is declared `mut`), and that change would be visible to the outer function (since it's done in the same stack frame), if not for the fact that the outer function isn't allowed to use the value after giving up ownership of it.

Comment: Also the compiler may be able to "flow" the code such that the parameters and return values never have to leave their registry, and don't even touch the stack. An other possible factor is RVO, where the return value is constructed directly in the caller's stackframe (the caller reserves space for the return value, and the callee works directly in that space).